buildozer で android.api 34 以上でエラーが出てしまう
タイトルの通りで、apiレベル34以上を指定してaabにビルドした際にエラーがでます。
まだbuildozerが未対応なのでしょうか?
buildozerのバージョンは1.5.0です。
エラー内容としましては、以下のようなものになります。
  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 166, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 34, in build_arch
    '--enable-shared', _env=env)
  File "/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/rill/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/rill/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/rill/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77:

  RAN: /home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_35/libffi/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_35/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... /home/rill/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make -j1 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j1 supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/rill/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi35 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/rill/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_35/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

config.log
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = i-52100000580856
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-66-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
PATH: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
PATH: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools
PATH: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
PATH: /home/ubuntu/environments/my_env/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2703: checking build system type
configure:2717: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2737: checking host system type
configure:2750: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
configure:2770: checking target system type
configure:2783: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
configure:2880: checking for gsed
configure:2911: result: sed
configure:2939: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3007: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3018: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3073: result: yes
configure:3127: checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip
configure:3154: result: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
configure:3219: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3258: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3265: checking for gawk
configure:3281: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3292: result: gawk
configure:3303: checking whether make -j1 sets $(MAKE)
configure:3325: result: yes
configure:3354: checking whether make -j1 supports nested variables
configure:3371: result: yes
configure:3516: checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
configure:3543: result: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
configure:3812: checking for C compiler version
configure:3821: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC --version >&5
Android (8490178, based on r450784d) clang version 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)
Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android34
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
configure:3832: $? = 0
configure:3821: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -v >&5
Android (8490178, based on r450784d) clang version 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)
Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android34
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fomit-frame-pointer' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfloat-abi=softfp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=vfp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mthumb' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fPIC' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
configure:3832: $? = 0
configure:3821: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -V >&5
clang-14: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-14: error: no input files
configure:3832: $? = 1
configure:3821: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -qversion >&5
clang-14: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang-14: error: no input files
configure:3832: $? = 1
configure:3852: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3874: /home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -target armv7a-linux-androideabi34 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -DANDROID -I/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/kivyallineone/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1   -L/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/kivyallineone/armeabi-v7a conftest.c  >&5
ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3878: $? = 1
configure:3916: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libffi 3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libffi"
| #define VERSION "3.4.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3921: error: in `/home/ubuntu/environments/kivy_all_in_one_simple_app_to_abb_or_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_34/libffi':
configure:3923: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

